# Java swing SQLite path

Tags: java, database, sqlite

In my project I use the SQLite database, located in the folder

```
src/main/java/database/database.db
```

If I start the application everything works correctly and the database is opened for operations. If I compile the application and start the JAR file, the database is not seen. I do not understand where it should be positioned, thanks for the help

Comment: If you want to be able to write to the database, don't keep it in the `src`/`resources` directory.  Place the database in a well known location you can easily access, for example, on Windows something like `{user.home}/AppData/Local/{application name}` or on Mac OS, something like `{user.home}/Library/Application Support/{application name}`. Placing the database in the same folder as the Jar is prone to failure, as the "working directory" isn't always the same as the installation directory, besides, on Windows, it will complain about write access to the "Program Files" directory

Comment: and if I wanted to have an equal path for each operating system?

Comment: Not something that is typically encouraged, as different OSes have different concepts of where you "should" store application data. You could just store it in `{user.home}/.{application name}`, but I, as a user, would not like you (because I like to keep my home directory clean and under my control)